# jQuery .trigger('click') does not get fired in $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several buttons I would like to click upon pageload:

Any hints how I can do that?

I tried

```js
$(function() {
  /* ------- Init SSV Charts ------- */
  var $ssvBtns = $('.loadSSV');
  if ($ssvBtns.length) {
    $ssvBtns.each(function() {
      $(this).trigger('click'); //DOES NOT FIRE;
      $(this).html('CLICKED'); //DOES FIRE;
     // console.log($(this)); //GIVES THE 'a' OBJECT
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success rounded-0 loadSSV" data-id="1"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Test1</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success rounded-0 loadSSV" data-id="2"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Test2</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success rounded-0 loadSSV" data-id="3"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Test3</a>
```

The Click Event:

```
$(document).on('click', '.loadSSV', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked'); //NOT FIRED!
    var $btn = $(this);
    var $id = $btn.attr('data-id');
    if ($btn.hasClass('is-disabled')) {
        return false;
    }
    $btn.children('i').removeClass().addClass('fa').addClass('fa-spin').addClass('fa-spinner');
    $btn.addClass('is-disabled');

    ....
});
```

So it does not even come to this, as `console.log('clicked');` never fires

Comment: Where is the click event ?

Comment: @A.T. That's what `$(function () {` is.

Comment: Replace this

$(function () {

with $(document).ready(function () {

Comment: @PradeepSambandam that is not going to do anything.....

Comment: SHOWS the click is working if I add `$(function() {
  var $ssvBtns = $('.loadSSV');

  $ssvBtns.on("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked")
  }); if ($ssvBtns.length) { ... } });
` - perhaps you add the stuff it is supposed to do to the snippet I made for you?

Comment: What is the "click" doing?

Comment: @mplungjan The case it needs to be automatically clicked, not onclick.

Comment: @PradeepSambandam I added something for the click to do. OP'scode does not DO anything when the links are clicked - also your comment above does not change anything

Comment: It is working, when I created click function

Comment: The code you posted works: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQxrOb?editors=1010

Comment: True, found the mistake: the `$(document).on('click',...` was INSIDE the `$(function() { ...}` Not sure why this is related, but it works now, as you made it through codepen

Comment: Vote to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._ - shows how creating a [mcve] works to solve the issue